# How can I initiate a phone call programmatically on the iPhone in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I initiate a phone call programmatically on the iPhone in iOS 5? i tried the following code call functionality is working fine but when I click the cancel button, It is displaying black screen.

```
    NSString *phoneUrl;
phoneUrl=@"9866510857";

NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:phoneUrl];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Drop the // so you just have "tel:9866510857".  I'm not sure if they hurt, but they definitely aren't necessary (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html).

2) Make sure you aren't testing on the simulator; it doesn't have a phone app, so nothing will happen regardless.  Test on an actual iPhone if you haven't been doing so.

Comment: is it possible without country code? I think he/she should always add a country code before call.

Comment: I really don't know. In the US a country code isn't required... just try it out and see.